# Can we think of the Fourier series as a Bochner integral?

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-series

$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\|#1\|}$ $\newcommand{\vp}{\varphi}$ $\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}$ $\newcommand{\T}{\mathbf T}$ $\newcommand{\C}{\mathbf C}$

Let $\T$ denote the unit circle and $\lambda$ denote the normalized Haar measure on $\T$. For each $n\in \Z$ let $\chi_n:\T\to \C$ be the function which takes $z$ to $z^n$.

For any $f\in L^2(\T, \lambda)$ we know that
$$
f = \sum_{n\in \Z} \hat f(n) \chi_n
$$
in $L^2(\T, \lambda)$.
This means that
$$
\norm{f - \sum_{n=-N}^N \hat f(n)\chi_n}_2 \to 0
$$
as $N\to \infty$.

> **Question.**
> My question is can we think of the sum $\sum_{n\in \Z} \hat f(n) \chi_n$ as a [Bochner integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral)?

Here is the natural thing to go for. Let $c$ be the counting measure on $\Z$ and let $\vp:\Z\to L^2(\T, \lambda)$ be the function defined by
$$
\vp(n) = \hat f(n) \chi_n
$$
If $\vp$ were Bochner integrable then the integral $\int_\Z \vp\ dc$ exists and is nothing but $\sum_{n\in \Z} \hat f(n) \chi_n$ and things are fine.
However, the Bochner integrability criterion asks for the finiteness of $\int_\Z \norm{\vp}_2\ dc$, which is same as asking for the finiteness of
$$
\sum_{n\in \Z} |\hat f(n)|
$$
But since $\hat f$ is not necessarily in $\ell^1(\Z)$, we cannot say that $\vp$ is Bochner integrable.

In general, I would like to think of any infinite sum as an integral under the counting measure of a suitable function.
The fact that I am unable to do this for the Fourier series is a bit disconcerting.
Perhaps I am making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: $f$ seems to satisfy the requirements for being the 'vector-valued integral' of $\int \phi(n)dn = \int \hat{f}(n)\chi(n)dn$ as given in defn 3.26 of Rudin's functional analysis. Namely, for each linear functional $\Lambda$ on $L^2(T)$, $\Lambda \circ \phi$ is integrable and, moreover, $\int \Lambda \circ \phi (n) dn = \Lambda(f)$. I don't know how exactly relates to the wikipedia link.

Comment: @MondaleJr. I do not see how to show that $\Lambda \circ \phi$ is integrable. We need to show that $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |\hat f(n)\Lambda(\chi_n)|$ is finite. Can you please clarify. Thank you.

Comment: Like $\Lambda$ comes from inner product with some $g \in L^2(T)$, right? Then I guess you can use Cauchy-Schwarz and Plancherel on the sum to bound by $L^2$-norm of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: @MondaleJr. Using your suggestion the best I am able to manage is that $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |\hat f(n) \Lambda(\chi_n)| = \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |\hat f(n)| |\langle \chi_n, g\rangle |$ which by Cauchy-Schwarz is at most $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |\hat f(n)| \| g \|_2$. Thus I face the same issue I face using the wikipedia caharacterization.

Comment: Uhh, write it as $\sum |\hat{f}(n)||\hat{g}(n)|$. On finite subsets this is going to be less than $\sqrt{\sum|\hat{f}(n)|^2}\cdot \sqrt{\sum|\hat{g}(n)|^2}$ which is equal to $ \|f\|\|g\|$?

Comment: @MondaleJr. This makes a lot of sense. Thanks. I am now puzzled as to why there is a discrepency between Rudin and Wikipedia. Perhaps you can frame your comment as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm confused as well. I've never seen 'Bochner' integrals before but maybe it's something like the distinction between strong and weak topologies? Bochner integrability might imply 'weak integrability' of Rudin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ seems to satisfy the requirements for being the 'vector-valued integral' of $\int \phi(n)dn = \int \hat{f}(n)\chi(n)dn$ as given in defn 3.26 of Rudin's functional analysis. Namely, for each linear functional $\Lambda$ on $L^2(T)$, $\Lambda\circ \phi$ is integrable and, moreover, $\int \Lambda \circ \phi(n)dn = \Lambda(f)$. I don't know how this relates to Bochner integrability.